# Efficiently finding NSManagedObject (Polygon) that a given point is within

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to find if a given point (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`) is within a Polygon NSManagedObject.

My Polygon object is defined as:

```
public class Polygon: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var points: NSOrderedSet?
    @NSManaged var centroid: Point?
    @NSManaged var computed : NSNumber!
}
```

And the Point object:

```
public class Point: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber!
    @NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber!
}
```

My current method uses this for creating the predicate for `Polygon` objects:

```
public static func nearbyPredicate(offset offset: Double, nearLocation location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> NSPredicate {
    let maxLat = location.latitude + offset
    let minLat = location.latitude - offset
    let maxLong = location.longitude - offset
    let minLong = location.longitude + offset
    return NSPredicate(format: "(centroid.latitude <= %@) && (centroid.latitude >= %@) && (centroid.longitude >= %@) && (centroid.longitude <= %@) && (computed == false)", argumentArray: [maxLat, minLat, maxLong, minLong])

}
```

Where `offset` is an arbitrary search 'radius'. The `computed` property is a boolean that I set to `true` once I have tried to detect if the `Polygon` contains the given point so that subsequent fetch calls exclude the object (as seen in the predicate). For detection, I first fetch `Polygon`s with that predicate above, then use this:

```
let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D // ... point to test
for poly in polysFetched {
    poly.computed = NSNumber(bool: true)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: (poly.points!.array as! [Point]).first!.longitude.doubleValue, y: (poly.points!.array as! [Point]).first!.latitude.doubleValue)) //set initial point

    for pt in poly.points!.array as! [Point] {
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: pt.longitude.doubleValue, y: pt.latitude.doubleValue))
    }

    if (CGPathContainsPoint(path.CGPath, nil, CGPoint(x: location.longitude, y: location.latitude), false)) {
        print("Poly \(poly) matches location \(location)")
        return
     }
}
```

This can be computationally heavy. The polygons I'm testing against can be quite large and oddly shaped.

Is there anyway to make this process more efficient using Core Data? Is there a way to offset the computation of calculating the containment of a point in an `NSFetchRequest` or in other ways?

Comment: I suggest you give the [Point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) a read first. And don't worry about performance unless it is a bottleneck for your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up resolving this in a few ways and sped up the process significantly. Since the `Point` NSManagedObject only existed for the purpose of fetching them via the `Polygon` relationships and computing the path (`UIBezierPath`) for the `Polygon`, I just computed the path during the creation of the `Polygon` object and stored it as a property. I also changed the `Centriod` relationship into the two properties `c_lat`, `c_long` and removed the `Point` class altogether! Indexing the `c_lat` and `c_long` properties sped up fetch requests too.

The new `Polygon` class is:

```
public class Polygon: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged internal var pathData : NSData!
    @NSManaged internal var c_lat : NSNumber!
    @NSManaged internal var c_long : NSNumber!
    @NSManaged var computed : NSNumber!

    var path : UIBezierPath {
        get {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(pathData) as! UIBezierPath
        }
        set {
            pathData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newValue)
        }
    }

    var centroid : CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: c_lat.doubleValue, longitude: c_long.doubleValue)
        }
        set {
            c_lat = newValue.latitude
            c_long = newValue.longitude
        }
   }

    func containsLocation(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        return self.path.containsPoint(CGPoint(x: location.latitude, y: location.longitude))
    }

}
```

Code Different's comment on my original post suggested the Wikipedia page for detecting points in polygons, but conveniently that is abstracted away from me with `UIBezierPath` and there exists a function `CGPathContainsPoint` that takes a boolean as its last argument to choose between the two algorithms for detecting points in polygons mentioned in the Wikipedia article.

For those encountering the same or similar issues that I did, I recommend inlining relationships and using computed properties to access non-primitive types of data you'd like to store in Core Data.

Comment: Note that geographic locations use spherical geometry and `UIBezierPath` uses planar geometry, so there will be cases where `containsPoint` is inaccurate. Unless you're working with especially large regions, though, the amount of error is probably negligible.